# PayPal exress checkout Malformated JSON

Tags: json, paypal-sandbox

I am nearing the completion of my web app, which uses PayPal express checkout.

Within my form, I have a hidden input that contains a JSON of the products in the shopping cart. The following is an example of what the JSON would look like:

```
    {
    "id": "8",
    "name": "Austin to Carls 32 to 33 chocolates to oil",
    "price": "9.67",
    "category": "oils",
    "description": "The standard Lorem Ipsum passage, used since the 1500s Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.Ut enim ad minim veniam,quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident,sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Section 1.10.32 of de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum, written by Cicero in 45 BC Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt.Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur ? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur",
    "ts": "2019-01-08 11:47:09",
    "product_image_id": "33",
    "enabled": "1",
    "product_image": "crater-winslow-40.png",
    "counter": 1
  },
  {
    "id": "9",
    "name": "something test 3 upd",
    "price": "12.23",
    "category": "chocolates",
    "description": "The standard Lorem Ipsum passage, used since the 1500s Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.Ut enim ad minim veniam,quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident,sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Section 1.10.32 of de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum, written by Cicero in 45 BC Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt.Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur ? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur",
    "ts": "2019-01-08 08:54:49",
    "product_image_id": "29",
    "enabled": "1",
    "product_image": "40-64-grand-canyon.png",
    "counter": 2
  }
```

When I take that JSON, surround it with "[" and "]", followed by pasting that in jsonlint.com's validator, I receive a valid JSON response.

However, when I post this exact JSON, which comes in the form of the following:

```
         item_list: {
          items: document.getElementById("product").value,
          shipping_address: {
            recipient_name:
```

Notice the - document.getElementById("product").value,

Which changes it into malformated JSON:

```
    items: "{"id":"8","name":"Austin to Carls 32 to 33 chocolates to oil","price":"9.67","category":"oils","description":"The standard Lorem Ipsum passage, used since the 1500s Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.Ut enim ad minim veniam,quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident,sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Section 1.10.32 of de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum, written by Cicero in 45 BC Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt.Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur ? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur","ts":"2019-01-08 11:47:09","product_image_id":"33","enabled":"1","product_image":"crater-winslow-40.png","counter":1},{"id":"9","name":"something test 3 upd","price":"12.23","category":"chocolates","description":"The standard Lorem Ipsum passage, used since the 1500s Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.Ut enim ad minim veniam,quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident,sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Section 1.10.32 of de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum, written by Cicero in 45 BC Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt.Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur ? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur","ts":"2019-01-08 08:54:49","product_image_id":"29","enabled":"1","product_image":"40-64-grand-canyon.png","counter":2}"
```

This returns the following error in the dev console:

```
http.js:147 POST https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment 400 (Bad Request)

zone.js:192 Uncaught Error: Error: Request to post https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment failed with 400 error. Correlation id: 75670a0d8c961, 75670a0d8c961

{
    "name": "MALFORMED_REQUEST",
    "message": "Incoming JSON request does not map to API request",
    "information_link": "https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#MALFORMED_REQUEST",
    "debug_id": "75670a0d8c961"
}
```

How can I fix this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

OK, this issue was solved by the following:

```
item_list: {
          items: JSON.parse([document.getElementById("product").value]),
```

[image]

However, since an element of my JSON is "category" PayPal is having an issue with the following error, but I will have to take that up with PayPal. I thought I would post this in case anyone else has an element to their product's JSON called "category":

```
    Error: Request to post https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment failed with 400 error. Correlation id: c4d516c6ef58b, c4d516c6ef58b

{
    "name": "VALIDATION_ERROR",
    "details": [
        {
            "field": "transactions.item_list.items.category",
            "issue": "Cannot construct instance of `com.paypal.platform.payments.model.rest.types.ItemCategory`, problem: oils is invalid value. Supported values are PHYSICAL, DIGITAL"
        }
    ],
    "message": "Invalid request - see details",
    "information_link": "https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/#errors",
    "debug_id": "c4d516c6ef58b"
```